# How to return a json respone or redirect to other view depending on the condition?

Tags: java, spring, return, return-type

I have a search criteria depending on which i get the list as a result .
If the list contains only 1 data then i want to return to the edit view of that particular data.If list contains more than 1 data i want to return the jsonResponse to show the data table .

I tried with this but i did not get the data table nor did i get the view

```
if(reservationGridDataPage.getSize() > 1){
    GridJSONResponse jsonResponse = ReservationGridHelper.prepareResponse(reservationGridDataPage);
    jsonResponse.setiTotalDisplayRecords(gridManager.getTotalSearchedReservations(pageRequest, null, entityStateCode, searchParams));
    jsonResponse.setsEcho(sEcho);
    return jsonResponse;
}else{
    Long entityKey = null;
    List<ReservationGridData> content = reservationGridDataPage.getContent();
    for (ReservationGridData t : content) {
        entityKey = t.getId();
    }

    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/xxx/editRes?id="+entityKey);
    return new ModelAndView(redirectView);
}
```

Comment: What is the return value of the method? It wont work because in if block you return `GridJSONResponse` while in else block you return `ModelAndView` unless `GridJSONResponse` is a subclass of `ModelAndview` which is contextually not right.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the view name which is of type`String`. Then, if `reservationGridDataPage.getSize() > 1` returns true, redirect to another method of the controller anotated with `@ResponseBody` that will return your json object.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "//... your mapping blah blah ...", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String method1(){
    if(reservationGridDataPage.getSize() > 1){
        return "redirect:/json-response.do";
    }else{
        Long entityKey = null;
        List<ReservationGridData> content = reservationGridDataPage.getContent();
        for (ReservationGridData t : content) {
            entityKey = t.getId();
        }

        //...
        //some other codes

        return "the-name-of-my-edit-view";
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/json-response.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody GridJSONResponse jsonResponseController(){
    //... some other codes
    GridJSONResponse jsonResponse = ReservationGridHelper.prepareResponse(reservationGridDataPage);
    jsonResponse.setiTotalDisplayRecords(gridManager.getTotalSearchedReservations(pageRequest, null, entityStateCode, searchParams));
    jsonResponse.setsEcho(sEcho);
    //...

    return GridJSONResponse;
}
```